# How to disable an input after enabling a checkbox?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Please tell me how can I disable input after checked checkbox without refresh page?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" asp-for="Way" value="@Model.Way" />

<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Road" />
```

1. User checked checkbox - > Text input disabled
2. User unchecked checkbox - >  Text input enabled